children' are specified twice. The attribute named 'children' will be overwritten in chakra ui
I am creating office addin task pane addin . for UI I want to use chakra UI react. In Index.js file i am wraping my app in chakra UI provider. and I am facing error.
'children' are specified twice. The attribute named 'children' will be overwritten.'
import * as React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./components/App";
import { FluentProvider, webLightTheme } from "@fluentui/react-components";
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react'
/* global document, Office, module, require, HTMLElement */

const title = "Contoso Task Pane Add-in";

const rootElement: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("container");
const root = rootElement ? createRoot(rootElement) : undefined;

/* Render application after Office initializes */
Office.onReady(() => {
  root?.render(
>     <ChakraProvider **value={undefined} children={""} ** >
      <App />
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
});

if ((module as any).hot) {
  (module as any).hot.accept("./components/App", () => {
    const NextApp = require("./components/App").default;
    root?.render(NextApp);
  });
}



Remove children={""}. The child prop is defined already -- as its the nested contents (<App /> in this case). Usually you do not specify children prop explicitly like that.

its working Thanks
